# Why does the addition of a dependency in Maven trigger functionality?

Tags: java, maven, openapi, springdoc

I have a simple question: I'm just getting started with Open API 3. For this purpose I have added the following dependency in Maven.

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.30</version>
    </dependency>
```

With the addition of this dependency, can I access the service via localhost:8082/v3/api-docs without having previously set anything and called a function of the dependency? How can this happen? What is the concept behind this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the OpenAPI dependency in your Maven pom.xml just adds the librar(ies) to your project.  That's all.

If this were a "traditional" project (like a JSP web app, for example), you'd have to write the code to create the web service (e.g. "localhost:8082/v3/api-docs").

But it sounds like your project might be Spring Boot:

> https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/java/tutorials/j-spring-boot-basics-perry/
>
> If you let it, Spring Boot will use its @EnableAutoConfiguration
>   annotation to automatically configure your application.
>   Auto-configuration is based on the JARS in your classpath and how
>   you’ve defined your beans:
>
> - Spring Boot uses the JARs you have specified to be present in the CLASSPATH to form an opinion about how to configure certain automatic
>     behavior. For example, if you have the H2 database JAR in your
>     classpath and have configured no other DataSource beans, then your
>     application will be automatically configured with an in-memory
>     database.
> - Spring Boot uses the way you define beans to determine how to automatically configure itself. For example, if you annotate your JPA
>     beans with @Entity, then Spring Boot will automatically configure JPA
>     such that you do not need a persistence.xml file.

Comment: Yes I am using Spring Boot. Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is called convention over configuration. 
Wiki link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration